# How to declare placeholders in Mandrill's text template?

Tags: mandrill

I am using mandrill in my application, and I need a template with placeholders.

The documentation specifies how to use them for HTML content

```
<span mc:edit="sectionName">Some content</span>
```

But it does not specify what to do in text content.

How do I add placeholders in text templates?

Answer (score 1):

You can use merge tags.
Like how you use mc:edit for HTML, you can use * |PUTCONTENTHERE| * (without white spaces between the * ).
And in the API call you can supply values for this merge tag as follows:

```
"message": {
    "global_merge_vars": [
        {
            "name": "PUTCONTENTHERE",
            "content": "Value for non matching rcpts in merge_vars"
        }
    ],
    "merge_vars": [
        {
            "rcpt": "emailadress@domain.com",
            "vars": [
                {
                    "name": "PUTCONTENTHERE",
                    "content": "Your value for this recipient"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
```